# Android TV App : Rejected - Not Designed in Landscape

Tags: android, android-tv, google-tv

This is what we are keeping getting from Google Review Team.

[image]

We have followed almost identical flow of what Netflix offers, there are none Letterboxing. I am now out of Options and looking to resolve the issue.

Is there a way we can figure out why our app is being labeled with this?

Everything is spread across the screen. Nothing like Portrait.

Here is our AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.grooflix">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />
    
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />



    <application
        android:name="com.grooflix.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:banner="@drawable/tv_logo"
        android:icon="@drawable/tv_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/tv_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyApp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m">
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.AvatarSelectionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.SelectLanguage"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.grooflix.Player.LiveChannelsMenu"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.Player.LivePlayer"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.EpgActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.grooflix.MenuActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.grooflix.SplashActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/tv_logo"
            android:icon="@drawable/tv_logo"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/tv_logo"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.ProfileManagementActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.EpisodesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.grooflix.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.DetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.Player.PlaybackActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.NoInternetActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.SimilarVideoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.Player.PlayerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.LoginNewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name="com.grooflix.SuggestedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi Yes.
There were two things we did to get it fixed
1) Overscan, some of our menu was going out of the LED screen, there is this feature of Samsung TVs, which zooms the screen, so we added the padding of like 10 pts 

2) Everytime Google Developer was checking the same video, that video had a 4:3 Thumb in the start like for 5 seconds. He was rejecting it because our app was 16:10, after changing that to landscape, we don't have any issue.

Comment: hey I am getting same issue even i have done   android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Comment: how did you find out these adjact  issue ?

Comment: After struggling alot, we have like 4 Different TVs, and 4 Different Android boxes.
Can you share a Video of your app running on a TV, from Launching to playing a video?